# ScientificForm is not being applied

Tags: output-formatting

I am looking to compute the value of $\sum^{3249}_{n=58} 2^{n \choose 2}$, but when I try to execute `ScientificForm[Sum[2^Binomial[n, 2], {n, 58, 3249}]]`, I get a very large output.

Why is `ScientificForm` not being applied?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of that sum is an (exact) integer, so Mathematica will display every digit because they're all significant. To get the output you're looking for, you just have to convert the result to a floating point number using `N`.

```
ScientificForm[N@Sum[2^Binomial[n, 2], {n, 58, 3249}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Large `Real` numbers are styled in ScientificForm by default, therefore all you need is [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html):

```
N @ Sum[2^Binomial[n, 2], {n, 58, 3249}]
```

> 2.782284487984395 x 10<sup>1588347</sup>

If you want to automatically display large `Integer` numbers in the same form you could use an assignment to [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24PrePrint.html), among other options.  This does not affect the internal value of expressions.

```
$PrePrint = # /. i_Integer /; i > 1*^50 :> N[i] &;

s = Sum[2^Binomial[n, 2], {n, 58, 3249}]
```

> 2.782284487984395 x 10<sup>1588347</sup>

```
Head[s]
```

> Integer